# how to create db back up jobs in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (X64) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit)

i need to create a job for the SQL database to backup everyday

with a different set of new files

i tried doing it and it over rites everyday

i wanted it to create new files everyday...

Plz help me as soon as...

Note:

```
     If i want to create separate folder for each day and stored the back up...
```

How can i do that plz help me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that version include the SQL Agent you can schedule a backup with a SQL script like that:

**Edit**: corrected code to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(1000)
set @sql='BACKUP DATABASE YourDB TO DISK = ''D:\Backups\YourDB-'+convert(char(8),getdate(),112)+'.bak'''
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a [Maintenance Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) and make use of the [Back Up Database Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189647.aspx). Taking a look at our backup schedule this generates a new file for the backup each day, with a date and time stamped filename. I believe this is in fact the default and as a consequence for our scenario we also have a cleanup task to delete older backups.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no solution using SSMS, you might try my Powershell script [automssqlbackup](http://www.devio.at/index.php/automssqlbackup).

Comment: Err, false, if that version have SQL Agent you can use SSMS to schedule a backup job with the SQL Agent using T-SQL.